# Is there a way to pinpoint the locations of the special enchanters?

Tags: torchlight-2

In my first playthrough of the game, I started a notebook where I wrote down all the act numbers and dungeon names of all the special enchanter locations (Boris the Stout, etc) as I came upon them.  Now I am on my second playthrough and I am finding entirely differently enchanters or sometimes no enchanters at all.  I researched a bit and it appears that the locations of these special enchanters are completely random.

I'd like to think that there is some way to know where to look for a specific enchanter.  Surely, it can't be *completely* random.  Is there at least a known cycle of locations where these enchanters can be found?

Comment: I don't think I've seen a comprehensive list anywhere.  Keep it up with your notebook and you may be the first!

Comment: Does anyone have anything on this?

Comment: @jw013 I found a nice list that sums them all up.  See below?

Answer (score 1):

Of course everything is subject to random generation, but there is a very good baseline guide at [SegmentNext by Ali Asif](http://segmentnext.com/2012/09/28/torchlight-2-enchanters-locations-guide-enchanting-tips/).  Lots of good stuff in the comments, too.

Comment: A quick glance shows that the list is incomplete.  I remember seeing enchanters in some locations not in the list.